# Run sencha application via Eclipse+ADT Bundle

Tags: eclipse, sencha-touch, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm getting started with Sencha Touch via [this official tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started) and in the same time I can run the Hello application via the tool `Eclipse-ADT Bundle` as guided [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

But I don't know how to use ADT Bundle to run the Sencha Touch application.

Answer (score 0):

We need to install Phone Gap so that Sencha web page will be provided extra javascripts API to access the device API.

And we also need a way to wrap Sencha web inside an Android native app project. This is done also done by PhoneGap - detail steps are greatly guided [here by Andrew Trice from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html)